# How to change the default directory for CSS using brackets, on macbook?

Tags: brackets

I am new to sass. My sass generate .CSS files in the same directory but I want to keep my .CSS files in separate directory? In my project folder I have JS, CSS, SCSS folders. I can do it in Sublime but I for no reason don't like sublime and I use bracket on Mac OS Sierra. I use brackets-sass plugin to generate CSS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

1. On the [brackets-sass plugin](https://github.com/jasonsanjose/brackets-sass) page there is a [preferences](https://github.com/jasonsanjose/brackets-sass#preferences) section. It contains all the settings you can put into your preferences file to configure this plugin.
2. Go to Debug -> Open Preferences File. That will open 2 files with default preferences and brackets.json, where you can put your own configuration.
3. In your brackets.json add [this config](https://github.com/jasonsanjose/brackets-sass#sample-bracketsjson-file)

However, there are quite a lot of issues opened on this plugin's repository and even easier way to compile Sass (out of Brackets) would be to use one of apps like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/).

Comment: Hej jrkn thank you very much. I put the code in my in my brackets.json but its not working :(

Comment: That's why I wrote about Koala. There is even a better way that lets you either only compile Sass to CSS or even build larger tasks, like compiling Sass, optimizing images, moving files, running Browser Sync etc. Have a look at [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) - 2 most popular tools these times

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Koala just worked for me. So I do like this, I create new project with folder like CSS, SASS, JS etc and I create style.scss file in SASS using Bracket. It created style.css and style.map files in sass folder. Then I opend my project folder  in Koala and Compile style.scss file there and it created style.css and style.map files in CSS folder. Am I doing it correctly? So everytime I have to do like this or I am doing it wrong? I am totally new to this field please guide me :)

Comment: Koala will compile your Sass files automatically, it's also nice to check "autoprefix" option. All you have to do is set it up and forget it, because it's going to work in background, allowing you to write Sass code and generate the static CSS styles for the browser.

Comment: Sorry again, how can I set it up with Brackets? :/. I just install Brackets and Koala now everytime I create new project I go to koala and compile the scss file manually  to generate css file in my css folder.